# Passing parameters to tearDown method

Tags: unit-testing, oop, python-unittest, teardown

Suppose I have entity that creates SVN branch during its work. To perform functional testing I create multiple almost same methods (I use python unittest framework but question relates to any test framework):

```
class Tester(unittest.TestCase):

def test_valid1_url(self):
    url="valid1"
    BranchCreator().create_branch(url)
    self.assertUrlExists(url) # assume I have this method implemented

def test_valid2_url(self):
    url="valid2"
    BranchCreator().create_branch(url)
    self.assertUrlExists(url) # assume I have this method implemented

def test_invalid_url(self):
    url="invalid"
    self.assertRaises(ValueError, BranchCreator().create_branch, url)
```

After each test I want to remove the resulting branch or do nothing if test failed. Ideally I would use something like following:

```
@teardown_params(url='valid1')
def test_valid1_url(self):

def tearDown(self, url):
    if (url_exists(url)): remove_branch(url)
```

But tearDown does not accept any parameter. 
I see few quite dirty solutions:

a) create field "used_url" in Tester, set it in every method and use in tearDown:

```
def test_valid1_url(self):
    self.used_url="valid1"
    BranchCreator().create_branch(self.used_url)
    self.assertUrlExists(url) 
...
def tearDown(self):
    if (url_exists(self.used_url)): remove_branch(self.used_url)
```

It should work because (at least in my environment) all tests are run sequentally so there would be no conflicts. But this solution violates tests independency principle due to shared variable, and if I would manage to launch tests simultaneously, it will not work.

b) Use separate method like `cleanup(self, url)` and call it from every method

Is there any other approach?

Comment: There are some who believe ``tearDown`` should never have been added to testing frameworks. Making your ``b`` solution the correct one. I would create a parameterized test with the proper exception handling to eliminate the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the b) solution could work even if it mandates to have the call to the helper method in every test and that sounds to me like a sort of duplication.
Another approach could be the calling the helper method inside the "assertUrlExists" function. In this way the duplication is removed and you can avoid to check again the existence of the URL in order to manage the cleanup: you have the assertion result and you can use it.